# Messages lost when consuming from BlockingCollection in batches

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, task-parallel-library, blockingcollection

I've tried to invent a method to consume a batch from `BlockingCollection` and got in trouble.

Here's a minimal repro:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static readonly BlockingCollection<string> _bc = new BlockingCollection<string>(1000);
    private static int _consumed;

    static void Main()
    {
        Task.Run(() => Producer());
        Task.Run(() => Consumer());
        Console.WriteLine("press [ENTER] to check");
        while (true)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("consumed: " + _consumed);
        }
    }

    private static void Producer()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
            _bc.Add("msg");
    }

    private static void Consumer()
    {
        foreach (var s in _bc.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            var batchSize = _bc.Count + 1;
            var batch = new List<string>(batchSize) { s };
            while (_bc.TryTake(out var additionalResult) && batch.Count < batchSize)
                batch.Add(additionalResult);
            _consumed = _consumed + batch.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Few messages are lost (but not always the same number). If you can't reproduce it, try increasing the number of produced messages.

What I'm trying to achieve is to use the `GetConsumingEnumerable` method in the consumer (after some time I will call the `CompleteAdding`) and being able to collect a batch of messages of some size, if they're already present.

What's the reason of losing messages and how to use it right?

Comment: If I remove the `&& batch.Count < batchSize` part of your `while` loop, it works fine. That said, since it should re-enter the `GetConsumingEnumerable` loop, I'm not sure why it would miss the stragglers.

Comment: Yes. That's because `while` consumes everything and `foreach` loop exits after first cycle. Moreover, I see clear correlation between number of `foreach` loops and lost messages. Looks like each loop after first one somehow loses one message

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wow. It's a bug. This line

```
while (_bc.TryTake(out var additionalResult) && batch.Count < batchSize)
```

should be

```
while (batch.Count < batchSize && _bc.TryTake(out var additionalResult))
```

since first condition has a side effect of removing item from the collection.

Comment: How simple it looks now and how blind I was for the last 2 hours

Answer (score 1):

```
 [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public IEnumerable<T> GetConsumingEnumerable(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      ...
        while (!this.IsCompleted)
        {
          T obj;
          if (this.TryTakeWithNoTimeValidation(out obj, -1, cancellationToken, linkedTokenSource))
            yield return obj;
        }
      ...
    }
```

and

```
public bool TryTake(out T item)
{
  ...
  return this.TryTakeWithNoTimeValidation(out item, (int) timeout.TotalMilliseconds, CancellationToken.None, (CancellationTokenSource) null);
}
```

both of TryTake and GetConsumingEnumerable use method TryTakeWithNoTimeValidation . i assume that missing elements were removed from collection by GetConsumingEnumerable. consider the following example:

```
private static void Producer()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"begin produce isCompleted:{_bc.IsCompleted}");
    for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        _bc.Add($"msg:{i}");
    _bc.CompleteAdding();
    Console.WriteLine($"end produce isCompleted:{_bc.IsCompleted}");
}
var batch = new List<string>();
foreach (var s in _bc.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    batch.Add(s);
    if (_bc.IsCompleted && _bc.Count == 0)
    {
       break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine($"first:{batch.First()}, last:{batch.Last()}");
Console.WriteLine($"consumed:{batch.Count}");
```

**_bc** is empty . 
there are a few ways to implement your algorithm , one of them i recommend to use Take and call consumer before producer(which blocks calling thread).